# how to insert dictionary value in python treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have create treeview

```
data=[{"sno": 1, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}, {"sno": 2, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}, {"sno": 3, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}]
```

above data insert into treeview

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class sales:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root=root
        self.root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (self.root.winfo_screenwidth(),self.root.winfo_screenheight()))
        self.root.state('zoomed')

        tex_frame = Frame(self.root, bd=3, relief=RIDGE)
        tex_frame.place(x=320, y=400, width=700, height=300)

        scrolly = Scrollbar(tex_frame, orient=VERTICAL)
        scrollx = Scrollbar(tex_frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)

        self.tex_table = ttk.Treeview(tex_frame, columns=("sno","item", "amount"), yscrollcommand=scrolly.set,
                                      xscrollcommand=scrollx.set)
        scrollx.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        scrolly.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        scrollx.config(command=self.tex_table.xview)
        scrolly.config(command=self.tex_table.yview)

        self.tex_table.heading("sno", text="Sno")
        self.tex_table.heading("item", text="Item")
        self.tex_table.heading("amount", text="Amount")

        self.tex_table["show"] = "headings"


        self.tex_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        global sno
        sno=1
        self.show()

    def show(self):

        data=[{"sno": 1, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}, {"sno": 2, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}, {"sno": 3, "item": "apple", "amount": 350}]
        self.tex_table.delete(*self.tex_table.get_children())
        for row in data:
            self.tex_table.insert('', END, values=row)

root = Tk()
obj = sales(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `for row in data: self.tex_table.insert('', END, values=list(row.values()))`.